# Excel how to change the value of output by change the value of input

Tags: excel

in the excel work sheet, if cell A1 is 3, cell A2 is 4, cell A3 is the fomula: "=A1+A2".  The cell A3 is 7.  If I like to change the cell A3 vlue to 10 by changing the value of A1.  That is, I change the value of A3 to 10 and like to see the value of A1 is updated to 6.  What should I do?

Thanks, Jian

Comment: You would need to do this in vba WorkSheet_Change event.  You can have a formula or you can have a user edited value but not both.  If you try to have formulas that refer to each other you will get a circular reference.

Answer (score 0):

You can do that by using *Solver* in the *Data* Ribbon tab:

[image]